# Categories Template Assistance

Tags: php, categories, templates, template-hierarchy

I have found a tutorial online for creating a custom categories template for my archived posts within a particular category. This however is targetting a specific category ID (see below), is there anyway of creating a template that targets all rather than one specific ID?

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Category-Tutorials
 * The template for displaying Archive pages.
 *
 * Used to display archive-type pages if nothing more specific matches a query.
 * For example, puts together date-based pages if no date.php file exists.
 *
 * Learn more: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Eleven
 * @since Twenty Eleven 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <section id="primary">
        <div id="content" role="main">

<header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="page-title">
                    <?php if ( is_day() ) : ?>
                        <?php printf( __( 'Daily Archives: %s', 'twentyeleven' ), '<span>' . get_the_date() . '</span>' ); ?>
                    <?php elseif ( is_month() ) : ?>
                        <?php printf( __( 'Monthly Archives: %s', 'twentyeleven' ), '<span>' . get_the_date( 'F Y' ) . '</span>' ); ?>
                    <?php elseif ( is_year() ) : ?>
                        <?php printf( __( 'Yearly Archives: %s', 'twentyeleven' ), '<span>' . get_the_date( 'Y' ) . '</span>' ); ?>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <?php _e( 'Tutorials', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </h1>
            </header>

    <ul class="category-7">
        <?php $archive_query = new WP_Query('cat=7&showposts=1000');
        while ($archive_query->have_posts()) : $archive_query->the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </section><!-- #primary -->
```

I was thinking maybe the following could be changed:

```
<?php $archive_query = new WP_Query('cat=7&showposts=1000');
```

Comment: If you find the answer to your own question, **that's great!** Please post your solution as an **answer**, rather than editing it into the question itself.

Comment: Hi Chip, i did post this i believe as an answer.... 0_o... sorry for the confusion there :)

Comment: Kirsty: I only see one answer: the one posted by @userabuser.

Comment: Hi Chip, not sure what happened then, as i know that i saw an edit. I must have posted it in the wrong box. Apologies

Comment: I do see an edit to your **question**, that includes your solution. You just need to move that solution from your **question**, into an **answer**. :)

Comment: Great Chip, i knew i werent going round the twist! :) I will move now :)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `cat` parameter from your query and name your template file `category.php`

From the WordPress Codex on [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy);

```html
 1. category-{slug}.php - If the category's slug were news, WordPress would look for category-news.php
 2. category-{id}.php - If the category's ID were 6, WordPress would look for category-6.php
 3. category.php
 4. archive.php
 5. index.php
```

The above denotes the order in which WordPress searches for template files and if it finds one that exists in that hierarchy, it will be used as the template for said condition.

So in this case you want to use `category.php` to create a global category template.

Of course, you can get creative and do all manner of things to meet all manner of conditions but if your basic requirement is as you describe then the above will suffice.

#### Edit

Replace this:

```
<ul class="category-7">
    <?php $archive_query = new WP_Query('cat=7&showposts=1000');
    while ($archive_query->have_posts()) : $archive_query->the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

...with this:

```
<ul class="category-7">
    <?php while ( have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Actually, get rid of the custom query code entirely. Just name the template file `category.php`, and WordPress will use it for all category archive index pages.

Answer (score 1):

I thought i would contribute my answer to the above. I have coded this to display my categories with a date, the person who posted it and a time it was posted, with a main title to display the title of the category in question.

Please see code and screenshot of what this produces, i hope this proves useful :)

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="maincontentwrap" role="main">
<h1 class="page-title"><?php
printf( __( 'Category Archives: %s', 'D-Theme' ), '<span>' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</span>' );
                ?></h1>
<div class="pagedivider"></div>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php the_content(); ?>
Written by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?> in <?php the_category(); ?> at <?php the_time('H:h a'); ?> 
<div class="pagedivider"></div>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Unfortunately i cannot screenshot due to lack of reputation on here, however [i will show you my site so that you can see this in action](http://www.milknhny.co.uk/DVine).